# Spaces as line breaks from inline for loop command

Tags: bash, find, osx, zsh

Someone care to enlighten me as to why the spaces in the first command seem to be interpreted as line breaks? Also occurs substituting print for echo.

```
$for l in $( find *.txt -exec head -1 {} \; ); echo $l;
```

```
9.16.11
09:20
9.19.11
18.41
9.21.11
07:15
```

```
$find *.txt -exec head -1 {} \;
```

```
9.16.11                 09:20
9.19.11                 18.41
9.21.11                 07:15
```

Comment: See [Don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the man page for your shell looking specifically at the IFS global variable.

Specifically, do this:

`IFS=$(echo -en "\t\n\0")`

Comment: echo $IFS | hexdump -c
Has revealed $IFS to contain "\t  \n  \0  \n"
But I'm still confused as to what I have to to keep the spaces from being interpreted as new lines?

Comment: try hexdump -C there are actually 5 characters -c is displaying, the first is ' '

Comment: In short, the space character is included in the IFS variable. To prevent that reset IFS: `IFS=$(echo -en "\t\n\0")`

Comment: @frogstarr78 - There's no need to use echo for that, in bash, just use `$'\t\n\0'`.

Comment: @ChrisDown I didn't know. Thanx

Answer (score 5):

Your command substitution induces word splitting on its output, based on IFS. Specifically, in this case it is splitting on spaces. Do not parse the output of `find`. Instead, do this:

```
for file in *.txt; do
    head -1 "${file}"
done
```

The Wooledge wiki also has some good information on this issue [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Comment: This won't break:  `set -f; find . -name '*.txt' -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file; do head -1 "$file" ;done` . . . The `set -f` disables pathname expansion